# Delphi SVN integration that works with SVN 1.7?

Tags: delphi, svn, integration, delphi-2010

I've just upgraded my SVN repository from 1.6 to 1.7. A major change to the repository format in 1.7 is that the ".svn" folders are no longer stored in each subdirectory; only in the root folder of the repository.

Unfortunately this seems to confuse the JCL SVN integration I have been using. It seems to think my files are not under source control.

Is there any Delphi SVN integration that works with 1.7 now or that has plans to support it in the near future?

I am using Delphi 2010.

UPDATE

There is a [bug report here](http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/bug_view_advanced_page.php?bug_id=5701) for the JCL SVN integration. Current status is "confirmed".

Comment: The [RAD Studio Version Insight](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=341542) has support for SVN 1.7 but I don't know if supports Delphi 2010.

Comment: @RRUZ: It does not since the OTA support used by VersionInsight was introduced in XE.

Comment: @Stefan I would guess it does by conditionally compiling some features only for XE. [delphisvn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphisvn/) originally supported Delphi 7 through 2007 and it had to reimplement some features from later versions to support Delphi 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been fixed in the latest development version of jcl. I now have the "Version Control" menu working correctly again in D2010. This is what I did:

Warning: Follow this at your own risk. There might be problems with this approach I am not aware of. We don't use JCL or JVCL much in our code, so if anything breaks it's not the end of the world. YMMV.

1. Download the latest daily build of JCL from http://jcl.sourceforge.net/daily/
2. Uninstall the old version of JVCL, by running the install.bat and asking it to Uninstall, but to not erase the existing folders.
3. Uninstall the old version of JCL, in the same way.
4. Run the installer for the new version of JCL.
5. Restart Delphi

I wanted to still link to the old (stable) version of JCL and JVCL, so I removed all references to the new version of JCL in the IDE's library path and replaced them with the equivalent directories from the stable version.

(Note: According to http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=Repository, JCL development is actually done in separate branches and the daily builds are as stable as the "stable" releases)

Answer (score 2):

Even Delphi XE2 seems to have some problem with this, even with 3 updates since the release, they never update the subversion client and I have to do it myself.

For the most part, I use tortoiseSVN, but collabnet svn commandline client is what comes with Delphi now.  I haven't used the JEDI stuff, we were using Source Safe and the visualconnexion connector until just recently. But, FWIW, you might want to install collabnet's subversion client and overwrite the DLL's distributed with JCL SVN. That worked for me with XE2 (although I don't believe it's the preferred method).

Comment: I can't find any DLLs that JCL uses. As far as I can see it's just a bpl?

Answer (score 0):

In this folder (\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\subversion) there is a readme.txt:

## "

## Information about bin/subversion.

This directory contains the Subversion .dll files used by the IDE's Subversion
integration.  These files can be upgraded by going to www.collab.net and
downloading the subversion client and extracting it to this location.  Other
subversion installations will not be used be default.  The IDE only looks in
this location, this behavior can be changed by setting the registry string
SvnDllDir under the Subversion key to the location of your Subversion
installation.  This will not work with all Subversion installation because not
all installation use the same .dll names.
"

I just copy the subversion dir from "RAD Studio\12.0" and it works.