# Delphi 10.3.2 - Add Project to version Control - Import to SVN Crashes Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, svn, ide

I am running Delphi 10.3.2 RIO. I have installed the latest version (x64) of Tortoise SVN (1.12.xx) and created several repositories. Using the Repository browser, I have the URL of the repository. I open a Delphi project and select Add to version Control -> SVN. Delphi IDE correctly identifies the files in the project (and those to exclude). I add a message and click import. After a couple of seconds I get the Windows message "Embarcadero RAD Studio for Windows has stopped working" and it literally crashes completely.

I have tried this with several different Projects and with several different repositories. I uninstalled the latest version of Tortoise SVN (1.12.xx) and installed the earlier version (1.10.xx). I deleted and recreated the repositories and repeated the Add to version control from the Delphi IDE. The result was exactly the same, ie. after a couple of seconds I get the Windows message "Embarcadero RAD Studio for Windows has stopped working" and it crashes completely.

I have not gone back to the previous version of Delphi and retried the SVN. That's on an Archived VM. If I did go to the trouble of resurrecting the D10.2.3 VM and it worked, what would it prove? Simply that a previous version Worked.

I can try and populate the repository manually (ie. outside of D10.3.2) and see if it works then.

When I have tried this with the previous version of Delphi, D10.2.3, it worked fine with SVN. I had expected it to simply import the project.

Notes:

1. I have seen this issue posted on another forum, but there was no response, so I am not the only one experiencing this issue.
2. I thought this may have been because the REPO was in OneDrive, but I moved it to my C:\ drive and the result was the same.

Two questions:

1. Has anyone else had similar experience with D10.3.xx and SVN?
2. Has anyone else with that problem solved it?

Thank you

Comment: You should file a bug report with Embarcadero. You'll need to provide them with more specific steps to reproduce than *I have installed the latest version (x64) of Tortoiose SVN*, because that doesn't affect the version in use by the IDE at all. (The IDE is 32-bit, and it doesn't use Tortoise SVN at all but uses the underlying SVN included with the IDE itself.)

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29942825/62576) to a previous question related to upgrading SVN in the IDE.

Comment: @KenWhite, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

After taking @KenWhite's advice, I find there is a defect already posted WRT this issue:

[Version Control Doesn't Work](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24050?jql=text%20~%20%22svn%22)

So a known issue with no fix.

Kevin